# menu with one combined background

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create one drop down menu out of these four lists

```
<ul id="list-nav">
<li><a href="#">1</a></li>
<ul>
<li><a href="#"></a>1</li>
<li><a href="#"<></a>2</li>
<li><a href="#"<></a>3</li> 
<li><a href="#"<></a>4</li>
<li><a href="#"<></a>5</li>
</ul>
```

```
<ul id="list-nav">  
<li><a href="#">2</a></li>
<ul>
<li><a href="#"<></a>1</li>
<li><a href="#"<></a>2</li>
<li><a href="#"<></a>3</li>
<li><a href="#"<></a>4</li>
<li><a href="#"<></a>5</li>


<ul id="list-nav">  
<li><a href="#">3</a></li>
<ul>
<li><a href="#"<></a>1</li>
<li><a href="#"<></a>2</li>
<li><a href="#"<></a>3</li>
<li><a href="#"<></a>4</li>
<li><a href="#"<></a>5</li>


<ul id="list-nav">  
<li><a href="#">4</a></li>
<ul>
<li><a href="#"<></a>1</li>
<li><a href="#"<></a>2</li>
<li><a href="#"<></a>3</li>
<li><a href="#"<></a>4</li>
<li><a href="#"<></a>5</li>
</ul>
```

But for some reason the css wont come together, i think i have been coding a while too long so i need someone to show me the css for it.
I want the menu to be inline and on mouseclick i want each undercategory to drop down.

Comment: How about you create the CSS for it, and come back and ask us about any problems you're having with it?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed the ul tags. except first and last one. And you are using id:s at four places. Id:s. Id should just be used once per page. Use classes instead.

Comment: btw. The numbers in the li tag should probably be moved to within the a tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start by correcting the a tags

```
<li><a href="#">1</a></li>
```

Instead of

```
<li><a href="#"<></a>1</li>
```

Make sure the numbers are inside the a tags an also make sure you close the all the ul tags.

As for interactivity you might need to use some CSS3 or JavaScript.

There are many tutorials around for doing this.

jQuery might be an easy way to go.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

There are a some serious errors with your markup:

- the same id is used multiple times. You should only use the same id
  name once in a page.
- The a tags are incorrectly formed.
- The drop down ul tags are not nested within the li
  tag of the parent ul.
- and the numbers of the drop down items should probably live inside
  the a tags

Corrections to the mark up are below.

```
<ul id="list-nav-1">
  <li><a href="#">1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="list-nav-2">
  <li><a href="#">2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="list-nav-3">
  <li><a href="#">3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul id="list-nav-4">
  <li><a href="#">4</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

With regards to what you are trying to achieve with the drop down behaviour, i'm unsure as to what you want. Could you provide a visual mockup of what the final result should look like?